# add something above of iPhone / iPad keyboard?

Tags: iphone, sdk, keyboard

i was wondering how can i add a view on ios Keyboard ? like this :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you will want to look into the `inputAccessoryView` property in the `UITextView` or `UITextField` class  (depending on what you are using) for a custom view above the keyboard.

Comment: thanks a lot ... what can i do if i want just show AccessoryView 
?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to only show the accessory view by itself then subclass your *UIResponder* view that presents the keyboard and redeclare inputView as read/write and return your accessory view in that method.

**Interface**

```
@property (atomic, retain) UIView *inputView
```

**Implementaion**

```
- (UIView *)inputView { return accessoryView; }

- (void)setInputView:(UIView *)aView { 
    if (accessoryView != aView) {
        [accessoryView release];
        accessoryView = [aView retain];
    }
 }
```

More information on redeclaring and adding both inputView and inputAccessoryView for any UIResponder subclass in the official Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html